# How to change colour of status bar?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I change the colour of the status bar on my iPhone 4s? It is blue now and I want it set to default?

Answer (score 1):

A blue bar is usually an indication something is using Location Services. It ought to say which app in the bar itself.

Check Settings > Privacy > Location Services to see which apps are allowed to do that & which have been checking recently.

[image]